# Assiging IIS Express SSL Certificate to a stie disconneted the rest of my IIS sites certificates

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm hosting a couple of sites on IIS 8.5 (Windows server 2012-R2).
These https sites are bound using a UCC SSL certificate from GoDaddy.

I created a new site on IIS and added binding using the "IIS Express SSL Certificate".
This caused the rest of my sites to stop responding to https requests.
I had to reassign the UCC SSL so my sites could work with HTTPS again, but I was wondering if anyone knows why this happens. Having these things happening in a production server is a nightmare so I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on this matter.

Comment: Windows Server 2008 R2 will go end-of-life in just a few days. It does not support SNI, so you only have IP based mappings to utilize, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background Well known issues, so most people won't consider that nightmares.

Comment: Installing a new SSL Cert on a server and assigning it to a new web site on IIS should not break any existing sites/bindings. Without having access to the server and reproduce the problem it is very hard to say what happened. If you have a single IP Address and bind a new cert to that, it affects other sites too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when you use the same IP or port with all the HTTPS sites. if you want to use the same binding with the different hostname you could use the SNI(Server Name Indication).

Server Name Indication (SNI), which is a TLS extension to include a virtual domain as a part of SSL negotiation. What this effectively means is that the virtual domain name, or a hostname, can now be used to identify the network endpoint. In addition, a highly scalable web hosting store has been created to complement SNI. The result is that the secure site density is much higher on Windows Server 2012 and it is achieved with just one IP address.
It should be noted that in order for this feature to be used, your client browsers have to support SNI. Most modern browsers support SNI; however, Internet Explorer (of any version) on Windows XP does not support SNI.

When you assign the https binding to the site you just need to check the Require Server Name Indication checkbox.

[image]